# gather function in R to match patterns in character strings

Tags: r, function, subset, tidyr

I want to gather reshape wide table to long table. The columns i want to gather have a pattern. For now i only managed to gather them by their position. How can i change this to gather them by the patterns in column names? please only use the gather function.

I have included an example dataset, however in the real dataset there are many more columns. Therefore I would like to gather all columns that:

1. start with an `f` or `m`
2. are followed by one **OR** two numbers

   dput(head(test1, 1))
       structure(list(startdate = "2019-11-06", id = "POL55", m0_9 = NA_real_, 
           m10_19 = NA_real_, m20_29 = NA_real_, m30_39 = NA_real_, 
           m40_49 = 32, m50_59 = NA_real_, m60_69 = NA_real_, m70 = NA_real_, 
           f0_9 = 32, f10_19 = NA_real_, f20_29 = NA_real_, f30_39 = NA_real_, 
           f40_49 = NA_real_, f50_59 = NA_real_, f60_69 = NA_real_, 
           f70 = NA_real_), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
       "tbl", "data.frame"))

   df_age2 <- test1 %>%
     gather(age_cat, count, m0_9:f70 )
   df_age2

expected output (there will be many more columns that are not gathered). The `count` should of course count...

```
 startdate  id    age_cat count
   <chr>      <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
 1 2019-11-06 POL55 m0_9          NA
 2 2019-11-06 POL56 m0_9          NA
 3 2019-11-06 POL57 m0_9          NA
 4 2019-11-06 POL58 m0_9          NA
 5 2019-11-06 POL59 m0_9          NA
 6 2019-11-06 POL60 m0_9          NA
 7 2019-11-06 POL61 m0_9          NA
 8 2019-11-06 POL62 m0_9          NA
 9 2019-11-06 POL63 m0_9          NA
10 2019-11-06 POL64 m0_9          NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 test1 %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -c(startdate, id), names_to = c('.value', 'grp'), names_sep="_")
```

Or it could be

```
test1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(startdate, id),
      names_to = c( '.value', 'grp'), names_pattern = "^([a-z])(.*)")
# A tibble: 8 x 5
#  startdate  id    grp       m     f
#  <chr>      <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 2019-11-06 POL55 0_9      NA    32
#2 2019-11-06 POL55 10_19    NA    NA
#3 2019-11-06 POL55 20_29    NA    NA
#4 2019-11-06 POL55 30_39    NA    NA
#5 2019-11-06 POL55 40_49    32    NA
#6 2019-11-06 POL55 50_59    NA    NA
#7 2019-11-06 POL55 60_69    NA    NA
#8 2019-11-06 POL55 70       NA    NA
```

Or may be

```
test1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(startdate, id), 
     names_to = c( 'grp',  '.value'), names_pattern = "^([a-z])(.*)")
# A tibble: 2 x 11
#   startdate  id    grp   `0_9` `10_19` `20_29` `30_39` `40_49` `50_59` `60_69`  `70`
#  <chr>      <chr> <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#1 2019-11-06 POL55 m        NA      NA      NA      NA      32      NA      NA    NA
#2 2019-11-06 POL55 f        32      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA    NA
```

---

Or it can be

```
test1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = matches("^(f|m)\\d+_?\\d*$"), names_to = 'age_bucket',
        values_to = 'count')
# A tibble: 16 x 4
#   startdate  id    age_bucket count
#   <chr>      <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 2019-11-06 POL55 m0_9          NA
# 2 2019-11-06 POL55 m10_19        NA
# 3 2019-11-06 POL55 m20_29        NA
# 4 2019-11-06 POL55 m30_39        NA
# 5 2019-11-06 POL55 m40_49        32
# 6 2019-11-06 POL55 m50_59        NA
# 7 2019-11-06 POL55 m60_69        NA
# 8 2019-11-06 POL55 m70           NA
# 9 2019-11-06 POL55 f0_9          32
#10 2019-11-06 POL55 f10_19        NA
#11 2019-11-06 POL55 f20_29        NA
#12 2019-11-06 POL55 f30_39        NA
#13 2019-11-06 POL55 f40_49        NA
#14 2019-11-06 POL55 f50_59        NA
#15 2019-11-06 POL55 f60_69        NA
#16 2019-11-06 POL55 f70           NA
```

Comment: this matches solely based on that the column name starts with f or m right?

Comment: @Danka the last option 'yes'

Comment: as i mentioned in the question, i will have many more columns that i do not want to me matched and some of them will start with an m or f

Comment: @Danka it is not clear based on your example what would be the expected output i.e. your description is `start with an f or m`

Comment: @Danka to avoid the non-specific matches and if the pattern is following one or more digits after 'f' or 'm' `test1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = matches("^(f|m)\\d+_?\\d*$"), names_to = 'age_bucket',
        values_to = 'count')`

Comment: is the  pivot_longer function better than gather ?

Comment: @Danka If you check my solution, it can do a lot more than `gather` i.e. `gather` would only do the last option I showed, but `pivot_longer` can split it to multiple columns i.e. 'f', 'm' based on the names pattern.  So, it is a generalized option and I guess in the future versions, `gather/spread` would get deprecated

Answer (score 4):

Use `starts_with`:

```
test1 %>% 
  gather(age_bucket, count, c(starts_with("m"), starts_with("f")))
```

Comment: i have updated the question, as it was incomplete and misleading